# Clicking on the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ links to StackExchange.com before page is loaded

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

The behavior of the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ is different before and after the page fully loads.

While page is loading: Links to StackExchange.com

After page load: StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ (Showing inbox if you have new items)

This becomes a bug when you have a new notification in your global inbox, and you click on the SE logo, and instead of showing your inbox, it directs you to StackExchange.com.

Comment: +1 This is is ridiculously annoying.

Comment: +1, how did you even notice this?

Comment: @Popular, if I have a new notification, it shows the red circle, and I usually check those as soon as I get them.  So, sometimes I end up clicking it before the page is done loading.  I blame it on my slow internet connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the next build, clicking the MultiCollider will only take you to http://stackexchange.com if you have JavaScript disabled.

Otherwise, clicking it (even very early) will cause the regular popup to show up, possibly with a short delay (i.e. only as soon as the page is ready for that).

Comment: [cough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231150/clicking-the-top-bar-sometimes-loads-the-se-homepage-sometimes-shows-the-site-s). :-(

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is a kind of bug and IMHO this behaviour isn't what unobtrusive JavaScript should look like. This is especially annoying when behind a slow/flaky connection, as I am now. Every time I see the red number on top of the page I'll have to be aware that I have to wait until the page is fully loaded and because of the flaky connection I'll have to wait even longer before I'm back on the previous page.

I think the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ should be disabled (greyed out) or even invisible while the page renders and added or activated by the JavaScript that adds the dropdown behaviour.