# Messages drop-down just links me to Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

I have two new messages.  When I click the drop-down, it just redirects to Stack Exchange.  Stack Exchange's drop-down still works as expected.

It may be related to:
*[Clicking on the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ links to StackExchange.com before page is loaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68061/clicking-on-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-links-to-stackexchang)*

I have a fast Internet connection, but the notification bar at the top of the screen wasn't loading correctly, potentially causing a "virtual slow connection".

Comment: Do you have a slow network connection?

Comment: It may be related to - [Clicking on the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ links to StackExchange.com before page is loaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68061/clicking-on-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-links-to-stackexchang)

Comment: As addicted as I am to this site now, I check Stack Overflow on my phone ([HTC HD2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_HD2)). [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) on this device actually *never* manages to "unlink" to Stack Exchange. So whenever there's new stuff in my inbox, I'll have to go the long way.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now.  I'm on a pretty speedy connection.  Although, there did seem to be a delay for the notification bar at the top of the page.  That could have been virtually causing the "slow" connection.