# Stack Exchange Inbox takes me to Stack Exchange if I click before the document is ready

Tags: discussion, status-completed, global-inbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clicking on the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ links to StackExchange.com before page is loaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68061/clicking-on-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-links-to-stackexchan)

Every-time I see the red numbers on my stack exchange inbox, I get so excited I immediately click it.

However quite often I end up on StackExchange.com instead of opening the helpful dropdown to click to my question. From there I don't seem to be able to access my inbox, so maybe have that inbox be found on Stack Exchange or prevent the click through sooner?

Comment: That must mean you're clicking it twice - once to get the SuperCollider box up and once to click on the 'StackExchange' link that appears where the old link is. Are you double-clicking? Or maybe your browser's doing something funny - which browser? And you do get the same dropdown and inbox on StackExchange.com if you log in there.

Comment: @Rup, no one click, I think it happens because the document is not ready. If I wait and count to 5 usually is enough time and it opens the drop down with one click