# Please Unlink Stack Exchange menu to http://stackexchange.com from template level

Tags: support, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clicking on the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ links to StackExchange.com before page is loaded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68061/clicking-on-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-links-to-stackexchang)

After the page initial script run, following html changed from

```
<a class="genu" href="http://stackexchange.com">Stack Exchange</a>
```

to

```
<a class="genu">Stack Exchange</a>
```

So, if you click the menu [image] before getting the page init script run, it redirects to stackexchange.com unintentionally.

Please Unlink Stack Exchange menu to http://stackexchange.com from template level.

```
<a class="genu">Stack Exchange</a>
```

Comment: Oh, I have a new comment! Yay! *Don't click yet*... *not yet...*, *just a second...* **Do'h**, too soon... what are these weird off topic questions? I can't answer any of these!

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure this is intentional and part of a progressive enhancement scheme—if you don't have Javascript enabled, the button will still do something for you—it'll take you to http://stackexchange.com which has all the information from the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ and thus won't be entirely useless.

Answer (score 0):

It's common for me to click on that link before it is ready, specially with no indication as to what it's going to do at the moment.
An accessible alternative to removing the link is to open the popup **on mouse hover**, similarly to the profile link.