# Clicking on share reloads the page on a slow connection

Tags: bug, sharing, connectivity

Clicking on share reloads the page on a slow connection. Tested on Chrome 105.0.5195.102 + Windows 10. I don't think it should reload the page.  Demo:

[image]

Not sure if I should tag as bug or feature request.

Comment: This is what happens on [all JavaScript  powered menus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318238/323179) when you click before JavaScript is loaded.

Comment: @Laurel thanks in that case it reloads. It doesn't go to all items page.

Comment: @Franck Because in this case, the `href` attribute of the "Share" link is a link to the current question's page. This is exactly what happens with the other links listed in the linked question, except that they lead to a different link (i.e., what's in their `href` attribute).

Comment: The fact that "share" links to the same page allows someone who doesn't have JavaScript enabled to get the share link via right click and "copy link". (Sounds like you might want to use right click yourself.) It's the same philosophy as those top bar pages which serve as an alternative to each menu dropdown.

Comment: I'm going to vote to leave this open because it's not the same as the well known top bar bug. This is the only report I've seen for a refresh bug on the share link.

Comment: What kind of slow? [3G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G) (long latency)? What are the bandwidth and ping times (to *patents.stackexchange.com*)? I get a ping time of 30-40 ms ([4G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4G) in a relatively good location.) (Some local ones are, strangely, worse than that. At least right now.)

Comment: [The trial page](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/24890/should-a-patent-title-be-very-narrow-or-very-broad-or-does-it-not-matter).

Comment: @bad_coder Okay, there's also the "Edit" link on Q&A pages and the "Edit" link on Watched Tags and Ignored Tags. Just in case someone's planning to post about those ones too :-D

Comment: Related (includes JavaScript requirements): *[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)*

Comment: On that *patents.stackexchange.com* page, to work for most operations, like voting and *"Share"*, JavaScript is only required from *googleapis.com* and *stackexchange.com* (*googlesyndication.com* is not). From [NoScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) on Firefox.

Comment: Does anyone else notice the return of "doubleclick.net" (bottom left) at that strategic moment of a fraction of a second before refreshing? - could that be related?

Comment: This question is [being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381963/should-this-question-which-reports-a-bug-that-has-the-same-root-cause-as-anothe).

Comment: It would be quite easy to add some inline JavaScript that ensures the link is unclickable until the rest of the resources load. That way, someone who has JavaScript fully disabled will still be able to use it as a link, but people who have it _enabled_ won't end up accidentally reloading the page.