# StackExchange pull-down menu redirecting to main site when clicked

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, top-bar, stackexchange.com

Recently I keep on finding that when clicking the StackExchange pull-down menu which is at the top left hand corner of every site that instead of it giving me the pull-down menu options that it instead acts like a link which just redirects me to the the main [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) site. This is the pull-down menu button that I mean:

[image: StackExchange pull-down menu]

This appears to be some sort of bug which mostly occurs when the page has not fully loaded yet, and I guess that it has not realised that it is a pull-down menu and not a link. So I just thought that I should report it.

Comment: I guess you've provided the answer yourself. It's not fully loaded yet.

Comment: @Bart: Yes, it mostly happens when it's loading, but sometimes it happens when it has finished loading and say been on the page for more than 15 minutes.

Comment: And then there are no errors in the console for example?

Comment: @Bart: Nope, no errors.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you don't have JavaScript disabled? You might have installed some browser extension that block JS as well, even if not saying so. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68061/clicking-on-the-stackexchange%E2%84%A2-multicollider-superdropdown%E2%84%A2-links-to-stackexchan).

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I definitely have JavaScript enabled, and anyway, SE would tell me at the top with a red band if I didn't.

Comment: @Toroidal you might be blocking only part of it, the message appears as `<noscript>` as far as I know, which means totally disable JS - browser extensions/addons work in different way.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Well, I don't have any browser add-ons that would do that. And all other sites running JavaScript seem fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This drop down is brought to life by the power of javascript.

If the drop down doesn't work and this "link" appears to be *just* a link, that's not a bug and default behavior if the javascript is not loaded for whatever reason (domain hosting js for SE is blocked, or you have turned of js, or there are some problems with the network you're using).

The reason in your case - the javascript haven't just had enough time to load :)

(you could see that in the first seconds of the page load achievements and inbox indicators don't work also - for the same reason)

Comment: But sometimes it happens after I have been on the page for over 15 minutes, I'm sure that it had time to load in all that time.

Comment: @Toro That's again, problems with loading javascript. Have you encountered other problems that time, such as not loading of "help" drop down, achievements or inbox indicators or lack of real-time updating? Or anything other strange you stumbled into, apart from the Stack Exchange link not wanting to expand into the drop down?

Comment: Nope, that is the only strange thing that I notice.

Comment: I think it actually happens when I click on the link just as I get to the page before it has had time to load everything, well, that's how it currently is, I don't know about what happened before...