# Reputation icon links to Stack Exchange instead of the current network site

Tags: discussion, top-bar

Regardless of which Stack Exchange page I'm on, the top-bar [reputation icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4JkM.png) is an `<a>` that links to `https://stackexchange.com/users/<user:me>?tab=reputation`

---

When browsing (e.g.) Stack Overflow, this gives some unexpected behaviour.

When clicking the icon *before* the JavaScript captures the event to show the regular popup, I'm being redirected to Stack Exchange reputation tab.

Why isn't this a link to the current network site? For example, `https://stackoverflow.com/users/<user:me>/?tab=reputation` would make much more sense when browsing Stack Overflow.

[image]

Comment: I'm aware that the indicator shows rep from all the sites. But when clicking the icon, I'm expecting to stay on the current network site. Since the button should not redirect the user to another site in the first place, why redirect to Stack-Exchange instead of the current network site.

Comment: That would be hiding data. I don't think you'll find many in favour of that.

Comment: Mmm, the 'hiding data' makes kinda sense, but then why is the icon a link in the first place? Since the desired action is to show the popup?

Comment: I don't know the idea behind that, but it's kinda useful. If you now right-click on the icon and open the link in a new tab, you'll have a shortcut to your network-wide reputation.

Comment: A page which also doubles as a hub to network accounts, bookmarks, flags and all kind of things you might be interested in.

Comment: @0stone0 _"why is the icon a link"_ See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252612/348196).

Answer (score 4):

The goal of the reputation icon is to show reputation changes **across the whole network**.

If you want to see your reputation changes on the current site, go to your profile and it's there.

So having the fallback link to the network profile is expected and good UX in my opinion.